# change getValuesMap of Rw Spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pattern-matching

I am working with ForeachWriter[Row] to implement a custom spark sink.

And for the process function I want to get value of a field as an int. 
Hence if I suppose that my `val row = Row("city","name","age")` I want to get the age as an Int and the remaining fields as string.

```
def process(row: Row) = {

    val fieldNames = row.schema.fieldNames
    val rowAsMap = row.getValuesMap(fieldNames)
```

with the getValuesMap every field is parsed as a string.

I thought about pattern matching to change the getValuesMap function:

```
val rowAsMap =  fieldNames.map {
      case "age" => row.getAs[Int]("age")
      case _ => row.getAs[String]

    }.toMap
```

This is not working as it age is always written as a string in the sink, any help/ideas, to get values in the expected types from Row

Answer (score 0):

Could you add details on "not working"? Still returns "age" as String, throws exception, some other problems occur?

Overall, your solution seems ok, though I'm not sure about `toMap` call in the end - you're not providing a key to the map. Maybe try something like

```
val rowAsMap =  fieldNames.map {
      case "age" => "age" -> row.getAs[Int]("age")
      case rowName => rowName -> row.getAs[String]
}.toMap
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why are you putting that type casting logic inside `ForEachWriter[Row]`. If you want age to be in `Int` Its caller's responsibility convert the schema of `age` inside Row to `Int`, no?

Also, **I don't think there is a need of doing** -

```
val rowAsMap =  fieldNames.map {
      case "age" => row.getAs[Int]("age")
      case _ => row.getAs[String]

    }.toMap
```

`row.getValuesMap(fieldNames)` does the same thing.
Please check the [sourcecode for getValuesAsMap](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.scala#L388)